# When calculating commutators, do you multiply them, or does one act on the other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, commutator

I've become a bit stuck on how to calculate commutators. I understand [A,B] = AB-BA
but what exactly is AB, is it AxB (A multiplied by B), or is it A(B) (A acting on B)?

For example if $A=4x$ and $B=2x^2$,

Is AB, $A(B) = 4(2x^2)=8x^2 $,

or is it $AxB = (4x)(2x^2) = 8x^3$

I feel like I've really been overthinking this and now I am stuck!
Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: If you defined $A=4x$, why would AB be equal to $4(2x^2)?$. I don't understand this.

Comment: @AA10 OP must have interpreted it as a composition of functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ should really be *operators* and hence $\hat A$ and $\hat B$. As such, it should only make sense to deal with them when they are applied to a quantum mechanical state $|\psi\rangle$. So $[A,B]$ "means":
$$ \hat A(\hat B |\psi\rangle) - \hat B(\hat A |\psi\rangle), $$
so "A acting on B", but not quite in the way you have done in the examples.

If you now work in a coordinate specific representation, say position $x$, you would have:
$$ \hat A(x)(\hat B(x) \psi(x)) - \hat B(x)(\hat A(x)\psi(x)). $$

Operators that only contain powers of the position operators are "trivial" in this sense because $$ \hat x \psi(x) = x \psi(x),$$
and hence the commutator is the same as just applying the operators to each other (ignoring the wavefunction):
$$\hat A(x) \hat B(x) - \hat B(x) \hat A(x) = (4x)(2x^2) - (2x^2)(4x) = 0. $$

However, if one of your operators were something like $\partial /\partial x$ (like the momentum operator), then you *need* to apply that to a wavefunction to make sense of it. You cannot just deal with the operators.